# Disable an input field if second input (most current) field is filled

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript. I read this link and tried to customize it but it is not working: [Disable an input field if second input field is filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771281/disable-an-input-field-if-second-input-field-is-filled)

I want to allow people to toggle between two options-city and zipcode. I want to enable whatever field they chose last and disable the other. For example, if they are on the zipcode tab and press the submit button, whatever input it is in the zipcode gets submitted and not the city & vice versa.

The html is:

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a class="border-radius top med" href="#city">City</a></li>
<li><a class="border-radius top med" href="#zipcode">Zipcode</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="city"><label class="IDX-advancedText">City</label>
<select id="aht-home-city" name="city[]" class="IDX-select " autocomplete="off">
<option value="2115">Austin</option>
<option value="2718">Bartlett</option>
</div>
<div id="zipcode"><label class="IDX-advancedText">Zipcode</label>
<input class="IDX-advancedBox IDX-advWildText" id="IDX-aw_zipcode" type="text"
   maxlength="255" name="aw_zipcode" value="" /></div>
```

The script is:

```
var dis1 = document.getElementById("city");
dis1.onchange = function () {
if (this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0) {
  document.getElementById("zipcode").disabled = true;
  }
}
var dis2 = document.getElementById("zipcode");
dis1.onchange = function () {
if (this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0) {
  document.getElementById("city").disabled = true;
 }
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated! The website is http://austinhometeam.staging.wpengine.com/joyce-newsletter/

Comment: First of all, the ID of your select is "aht-home-city" and not "city".  The ID of your input is "IDX-aw_zipcode" and not "zipcode".

You also have a copy/paste error when your are defining the second onchange, you are defining it on dis1 but you want to define it on dis2

Comment: In addition to what @forumma said, this is very bad behaviour towards your user, who will not understand why his zip code input box is suddenly disabled. And vice versa. Also, how can the user now regret his choice?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I need to disable one or the other. If they enter zipcode that does not match the city the return result would be 0. Of course I can write arguments that pulls up the city when the zipcode is chosen and vice versa. But, I do not know enough javascript to code that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I told you in the comment, you need to change the ID in the "getElementById".

I also add the re-enabled the field when the other one is empty.

I add an empty value in the select, when the null is selected, the zip code's field return enable.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a class="border-radius top med" href="#city">City</a></li>
<li><a class="border-radius top med" href="#zipcode">Zipcode</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="city"><label class="IDX-advancedText">City</label>
<select id="aht-home-city" name="city[]" class="IDX-select " autocomplete="off">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="2115">Austin</option>
<option value="2718">Bartlett</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="zipcode"><label class="IDX-advancedText">Zipcode</label>
<input class="IDX-advancedBox IDX-advWildText" id="IDX-aw_zipcode" type="text"
   maxlength="255" name="aw_zipcode" value="" /></div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
var dis1 = document.getElementById("aht-home-city");
var dis2 = document.getElementById("IDX-aw_zipcode");

dis1.onchange = function () {
  if (dis1.value !== "" || dis1.value.length > 0) {
    dis2.disabled = true;
  } else {
    dis2.disabled = false;
  }
};


dis2.onchange = function () {
  if (dis2.value !== "" || dis2.value.length > 0) {
    dis1.disabled = true;
  } else {
    dis1.disabled = false;
  }
};
```

There is a working example :
[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/oqOMoDe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this behaviour?

```
var last = "";

var dis1 = document.getElementById("aht-home-city");
dis1.onchange = function () {
    last = "city";
    document.getElementById("IDX-aw_zipcode").disabled = true;
}
var dis2 = document.getElementById("IDX-aw_zipcode");
dis2.onchange = function () {
    last = "zipcode";
    if (this.value != "" || this.value.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("aht-home-city").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Check this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTvHb/)**

*Note: there was also a missing `</select>` tag in the HTML.*